Gif isn't playing, none errors
My gif file isn't playing, but there is no errors in console.
Render method:
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
   elapsed += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
   Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
   Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   batch.begin();
   if (animation != null) {
       TextureRegion frame = animation.getKeyFrame(elapsed);
       batch.draw(frame, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
       System.out.println("Frame " + elapsed + " played");
   } else {
       System.out.println("Animation is null");
    }
        batch.end();
}

Show method:
@Override
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("AfterBossScreen show() called");
        font = new BitmapFont();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        // gif load
        try {
            animation = GifDecoder.loadGIFAnimation(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP, Gdx.files.internal("begin.gif").read());
            System.out.println("AfterBossScreen: Animation loaded");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error loading GIF: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

I checked the GifDecoder and Animation classes, and i didn't find any bug.
